# Macro argument in the middle of a variable name?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

The macro:

```
#define TESTMACRO(name, exc) void* jt_name[exc];int jtix_name = 0;
```

Example:

```
TESTMACRO(testname, 2)
```

translates to

```
void* jt_name[2];int jtix_name = 0;
```

How could I make it say jt_testname instead?

I tried using a hashtag(#) before names, but that did not do what I wanted. Having spaces isn't an option because it's mid variable name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the concatenation operator (##):

`#define TESTMACRO(name, exc) void* jt_ ## name[exc];int jtix_ ## name = 0;`